# android 1.6 code gives nullpointer on 2.3.3

Tags: android

Hi I'm writing an android application.
I found a code snippet for xml parsing. I tested it on another project and everything worked fine. So I thought lets test it on my main project but then it gives me a nullpointer :S.

This is my ParseXMLDemo class:

```
public class ParseXMLDemo extends ListActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList vraag;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList a1;
private ArrayList p1;
private ArrayList a2;
private ArrayList p2;
private ArrayList a3;
private ArrayList p3;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String xml = ParseXMLMethods.getXML();
    Document doc = ParseXMLMethods.XMLfromString(xml);

    int numResults = ParseXMLMethods.numResults(doc);

    if((numResults <= 0)){
        Toast.makeText(ParseXMLDemo.this, "Er is een fout opgetreden bij het updaten van de vragen. Probeert u het later opnieuw.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        finish();
    }

    NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName("os");

    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
        Element e = (Element)children.item(i);
        vraag.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "vraag"));
        a1.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "a1"));
        p1.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "p1"));
        a2.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "a2"));
        p2.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "p2"));
        a3.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "a3"));
        p3.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "p3"));
        Toast.makeText(ParseXMLDemo.this, (CharSequence) vraag.get(i)+" "+a1.get(i)+" "+p1.get(i)+" "+a2.get(i)+" "+p2.get(i)+" "+a3.get(i)+" "+p3.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        map.put("id", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "id"));
        map.put("vraag", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "vraag"));
        map.put("a1", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "a1"));
        map.put("p1", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "p2"));
        map.put("a2", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "a2"));
        map.put("p2", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "p2"));
        map.put("a3", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "a3"));
        map.put("p3", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "p3"));

        mylist.add(map);            
    }       

    Toast.makeText(ParseXMLDemo.this, "testje"+mylist.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.list_layout, 
                  new String[] { "vraag", "a1", "p1", "a2", "p2", "a3", "p3" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.subtitle, R.id.sub1, R.id.sub11, R.id.sub2, R.id.sub22, R.id.sub3});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(ParseXMLDemo.this,o.get("vraag"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    });
}}
```

and this is my ParseXMLMethods class:

```
public class ParseXMLMethods {

public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return doc;
}

 public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node kid;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return kid.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 public static String getXML(){  
        String line = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.oudersvragen.nl/test.xml");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            line = "Internet Connection Error >> " + e.getMessage();
        } 
        return line;
}

public static int numResults(Document doc){     
    Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
    int res = -1;
    try{
        res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
    }catch(Exception e ){
        res = -1;
    }
    return res;
}

public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return ParseXMLMethods.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
```

}

Can Somebody tell me why it gives me a nullpointer exception in an android 2.3.3 project and why everything works the way its supposed on an android 1.6 project?
(FYI. I'm running the project on the same android 4.0 vm)

Logcat Output:

```
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.hgs.database/com.hgs.database.ParseXMLDemo}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at com.hgs.database.ParseXMLDemo.onCreate(ParseXMLDemo.java:57)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-05 20:50:33.561: E/AndroidRuntime(3705):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Comment: Please post the logcat errors.

Comment: Have you determined where in onCreate() the exception is raised via the debugger and breakpoints?

Comment: Its gives the error at:   int numResults = ParseXMLMethods.numResults(doc);

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you presented a complete program (excluding the layout), so I ran it. Here's what I found:

When I forgot to include internet permissions I discovered that calling `finish()` does not exit onCreate(). So I added a return command:

```
if(numResults <= 0){
    Toast.makeText(Example.this, "Er is een fout opgetreden bij het updaten van de vragen. Probeert u het later opnieuw.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    finish();
    return;
}
```

After including the internet permission, I noticed that you don't initialize your arrays, so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList vraag = new ArrayList();
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList p1 = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList p2 = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList a3 = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList p3 = new ArrayList();
```

And it now runs on my 2.3.3 emulator.

Comment: even when I add the return statement and initialize the arrays it gives me that nullpointer :S

Comment: Since I never encountered a null pointer, I wasn't certain it would help. Are you running this on a phone or emulator? What type?

Comment: I am running this on both my Galaxy SII android v4.0.3  and on my android 4.0.3 vm. And it gives me the error on both of them. But only from a 2.3.3 project. If I run it from a android v1.6 project everything runs fine. So its project related I guess not phone related